# Prevent jquery draggable from jumping in resizable droppable

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable, resizable

Trying to drop a draggable onto a droppable that is also resizable.  Everything worked fine until I added the resizable statement to the droppable.  Now the draggable jumps on release.  Is there some offset in the droppable that I need to account for?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#droppable").resizable();

var x = null;

//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

        $("#droppable").droppable({

            drop: function (e, ui) {

                if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                    x = ui.helper.clone();
                ui.helper.remove();
                x.draggable({
                    helper: 'original',
                    containment: '#droppable',
                    tolerance: 'fit'
                });
                x.resizable({
                    minWidth: 50
                });
                x.appendTo('#droppable');
            }

            }
        });
```

});

jsfiddle example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/78aAf/2/

Comment: The css left & top properties are causing your jump. Once the draggable is appended to the droppable (which has relative positioning) the top & left properties cause it to jump to that relative position. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78aAf/5/) that explicitly declares top and left to be 0.

Comment: Better, but I don't want the item to append to the top left.  I want it to stay where I actually drop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the css left/top as @czarchaic mentions, but rather than just setting to `0` you need to set to the drop position using `ui.offset` of the dropped element, and then take into account the offset of the drop zone, padding, margin and border widths.

```
x.draggable({
    helper: 'original',
    containment: '#droppable',
    tolerance: 'fit'
}).css({ top: ui.offset.top-6, left: ui.offset.left - 228});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78aAf/7/

[jQuery Droppable drop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)

Comment: This helped.  I added: var id = "#" + $(this).attr("id"); and changed the css to: top: ui.offset.top - $(id).offset().top, left: ui.offset.left - $(id).offset().left to allow for dynamic calculation of the droppable div's position.  Thank you.

Comment: Great, that's much better and makes it much more extensible.